# Baby steps to a solution with django and mod-wsgi on os x

Tags: python, django, apache, macos, mod-wsgi

I'm running apache / os x and serving up localhost pages to test django on my laptop.  I've already verified all the following

• python is working fine and up to date (2.5.1)

• django available to python and up to date (1,1,0, 'final', 0)

• mod_wsgi module is loaded among apache modules in my apache config - Check!

• path to django application is in vhost.conf with proper permissions - OK!

• mod_wsgi vhost.conf tested and working fine in the intended django application directory 
- test application through localhost pulls up 200 OK, 'hello world!'

• django default application has been created using 'django-admin.py startproject mysite'

• django application works fine on port 8000 using development server - OK!

• path to the new django application (called mysite) is on python path - verified!

All this is verified and when I run the wsgi script with DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE settings.py and load the django app, I still get 'could not import settings 'mysite.settings' etc.

Since this seems to cover the basic troubleshooting, are there any further steps I could take to find out the problem?

================

Python path is valid, verified.  The django development server runs fine with the command line on port 8000.

The apache config has the typical module loaded:
LoadModule wsgi_module  libexec/apache2/mod_wsgi.so

vhost.conf is included from apache config as follows

NameVirtualHost: *.80

```
    <Directory /users/useracct/scripts/python>
            Order allow,deny
            Allow from all
    </Directory>

    <Directory /Library/WebServer/Documents>
            Order allow,deny
            Allow from all
    </Directory>
    WSGIDaemonProcess localhost user=username group=staff threads=25
    WSGIProcessGroup localhost

    WSGIScriptAlias /mysite /users/useracct/Sites/mysite/mysite.wsgi

    <Directory /users/useracct/Sites/mysite/>
            Allow from all
    </Directory>

    DocumentRoot /Users/useracct/Sites/
```

Virtualenv is not set up with this account, so that is one less possible cause.

=======================

and the wsgi script file (trying to keep it minimal):

---

```
import os, sys
path = '/users/usracct/sites/mysite'
if path not in sys.path:
    sys.path.append(path)

os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE'] = 'mysite.settings'
import django.core.handlers.wsgi
application = django.core.handlers.wsgi.WSGIHandler()
```

Comment: In particular, focus on the `sys.path` settings and provide the working directory for your Django app (including the `settings.py` file).

Comment: Also, check that the application correctly starts via `./manage.py runserver` - if not, post any error messages.

Comment: Post the Apache configuration snippet showing how you mapped your application into mod_wsgi. Specially, show how you set path to Django application in Apache configuration and whether you are using mod_wsgi in embedded mode or daemon mode.

Comment: And what is in your WSGI script file? Post that in question as well.

Comment: @Graham It is as you say on your blog, "no one to blame but yourself" for a configuration error. On that front, there continues to be a specific stumbling block (present case included) in the developer community regarding the requisite curve to establish a development environment with meaningful feedback. One has to wonder why the configuration process has evolved without the feedback to get basic indicators in place on a new project. (Hence the title of 'baby steps' in this post). I suppose there is a log for that somewhere that is commonly not heeded.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try adding  /users/useracct/Sites/ a to your pythonpath in your wsgi file:

```
import os
import sys
.....
sys.path.append(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)) + '/..')
....
```

Comment: and btw, mod_wsgi is a great thing, but i find the python environment remains very hard to troubleshoot in. One thing I'm working on is a more feedback-oriented environment. Some way to maximize the test loop - but no GUIs. When you rely on a GUI it really starts to go downhill. Now that's a topic for debate.

Comment: Pythovore. Did you actually read the Django integration guide on the mod_wsgi site? It tells you quite explicitly about the need to add that directory. The answer here is being a bit smart about it, ie., by trying to calculate it relative to WSGI script file, but the need to add the directory is described in the documentation. Read 'http://code.google.com/p/modwsgi/wiki/IntegrationWithDjango'.